# How to compare two CSV files and their multiple strings and merge them into one if condition is met?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have two master files (let's call them **one.csv** and **two.csv**) and an instruction to parse them and merge into multiple files under a specific directory structure. I managed to do the first part of it and build a directory structure with underlying files. The only thing I'm not able to achieve on my own is the second and last part of my instruction. I will now simulate relevant content of both CSV files:

## one.csv:

1. ID,Status,Date,Asset,Frequency
2. **4815162342**,Open,29/02/1842,9765,Monthly
3. ...

## two.csv:

1. Service,Description,ID,Attribute,Activity
2. IDR,Conducting,**4815162342**,Done,**THEONETHATGOTAWAY_01**
3. IDR,Conducting,**4815162342**,Todo,**THEONETHATGOTAWAY_02**
4. IDR,Conducting,**4815162342**,Todo,**THEONETHATGOTAWAY_03**

*NOTE: The first line of both files, as it usually goes, is constant as it represents column name.*

The part that I managed to do is parsing **one.csv** and writing it, in the correct format, to multiple files (file01.csv, file02.csv, file03.csv, etc.), each containing a column name and its respective value starting from row 2; like so:

## file01.csv:

1. ID:,**4815162342**
2. Status:,Open
3. Date:,29/02/1842
4. Asset:,9765
5. Frequency:,Monthly

*EOF*

What my mind refuses to success in is, after parsing **one.csv** and writing it to files, open each file again, read that 4815162342 (as an example. it's different in every file, but the position of it is obviously the same), then go look for it in **two.csv** and, if it matches in a row, append the row's 4<sup>th</sup> element (THEONETHATGOTAWAY_xx) to **file01.csv**; like so:

## file01.csv:

1. ID:,**4815162342**
2. Status:,Open
3. Date:,29/02/1842
4. Asset:,9765
5. Frequency:,Monthly
6. 
7. **THEONETHATGOTAWAY_01**
8. **THEONETHATGOTAWAY_02**
9. **THEONETHATGOTAWAY_03**

*EOF*

This last **file01.csv** is my goal.

---

## What I tried so far:

To try and compare the two files for same ID and print if succeeded, I tried:

```
...
directory = '/home/user/work/'

with open(directory + 'one.csv', 'r') as one, open(directory + 'two.csv', 'r') as two:
    
    # One:
    sheetOne = csv.reader(one, delimiter=';')
    titleOne = next(sheetOne)     # First row as constants (ID,Status,Date,Asset,Frequency)

    # Two:
    sheetTwo = csv.reader(two, delimiter=',')

    for rowOne in sheetOne:
        for rowTwo in sheetTwo:
            if rowTwo[2] == rowOne[0]:     # Check if ID in one.csv row is same as ID in two.csv row
                print("Equal: " + rowTwo[2] + "&" + rowOne[0])
```

*EOF*

Instead of `print("Equal: " + rowTwo[2] + "&" + rowOne[0])` there will be

```
with open(directory + "output/" + rowOne[*] + "/" + rowOne[*].capitalize() + "/" + rowOne[*] + ".csv", 'a') as f_2:
    f_2.write(rowTwo[4] + ";")
```

once I figure out how to make it work.

My guess is that something is not right with that:

```
    for rowOne in sheetOne:
        for rowTwo in sheetTwo:
            if rowTwo[2] == rowOne[0]:     # Check if ID in one.csv row is same as ID in two.csv row
```

I'm pretty positive that the other answers wouldn't meet my specific need, but if my question were to be flagged as a duplicate I wouldn't be surprised, because I'm in no shape to play around with the script any more.

Comment: You could load both CSVs into Pandas dataframes with `read_csv` and then [merge them using concat or merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-or-named-series-joining-merging). Your desired output isn't a CSV at all though. Perhaps you should describe what you want to do, not how you expect to do it. Do you want 1 output file for each `one.csv` row? With one row per property? What properties do you want to export? In your example `Attribute` is lost. What happens if another property has multiple values?

Comment: I'll take a look at Pandas, as per your comment and Timeless' answer. Why don't you consider my output file CSV? Is it because of lack of commas after "THEONETHAT..." and newline? All my final files are to be printed, so it's all graphical. I want an output file for each one.csv row + appended rows from two.csv that share the ID. The files I generated are what I need, except that they miss the bottom part - the appended "THEONETHAT...". They miss that part because the file that I initially used - one.csv - doesn't have those strings, but two.csv does. Attribute is irrelevant, bold is relevant.

Comment: @ObserverSwarm178, did you give a try to the proposition below ?

Comment: @Timeless Yes! I believe I also flagged it as accepted answer and wrote a thank you note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A less overhead approach would be to use [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) :

```
#pip install pandas
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

dip = Path("/home/user/work")
out = dip / "output" # to be adjusted (if needed)

one = pd.read_csv(dip / "one.csv").add_suffix(":")
one.insert(len(one.columns), "", "") #to simulate the blank line

two = pd.read_csv(dip / "two.csv")

for n, id_ in enumerate(one["ID:"], start=1):
    head = one.loc[one["ID:"].eq(id_)].T
    tail = two.loc[two["ID"].eq(id_), ["Activity"]].set_index(["Activity"])
    pd.concat([head, tail]).to_csv(out / f"file{str(n).zfill(2)}.csv", header=False)
```

Output (`file01.csv`) :

```
ID:,4815162342
Status:,Open
Date:,29/02/1842
Asset:,9765
Frequency:,Monthly
,
THEONETHATGOTAWAY_01,
THEONETHATGOTAWAY_02,
THEONETHATGOTAWAY_03,
```

In a tabular format :

[image]

FF's view :

```
home
┗━━ user
    ┗━━ work
        ┣━━ one.csv
        ┣━━ two.csv
        ┗━━ output
            ┗━━ file01.csv
```

Comment: Beautifully done! Had to adapt the code a little bit and...that's it!! Works like magic.